# Windows Forms textbox taking up the space of another textbox even though it's docked

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEYtk.png)

I'm making a simple text editor, where the right richtextbox is the typing field, while the small richtextbox on the left is a counter indicating which line the user is on (like in Notepad++ or a code editor). However, the right richtextbox has 'Fill' selected as its docking property, while the small richtextbox is set to 'Left', but the right richtextbox is taking up the space reserved for the small richtextbox.
How can i fix this?

I've already tried using margins, but it doesn't work with dock enabled. When dock is disabled, it works, but I need it to be in 'Fill' mode because of a program feature (hiding the line count).

Comment: The following may be helpful: [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: @lucastozo7 I developed a similar idea in VB.Net with a RichTextBox I resisted this idea but I used a WPF TextBox and ElementHost1 concept It gave me spell checking and edit ability on the fly Just a thought seems simpler than two RTB's enjoy and welcome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on sequence which add container(or panel).
Let's try "BringToFront" as below(I can't find latest image...).

[image]